# jquery load() specific div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the portion of HTML in question as well Javascript related to it:

HTML first:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="content.html#diviwant">click</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript goes:

```
$("#menu a").click(function(){
var link=encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
$("#divtobeloadedwith").load(link);
return false;
});
```

`content.html` structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="diviwant">stuff</div>
<div id="dividontwant">stuff</div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking on link it loads all the content instead only specific div.

Comment: Remember as well that with the code that you have, you are taking `#diviwant` from content.html and putting it into `#divtobeloaded`. The naming of your divs implies that you have this around the wrong way.

Comment: `#divtobeloadedWITH#diviwant` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally the problem is that you want two different things:

1. When running without Javascript, you want to use the link `content.html#diviwant`, as that will load the page `content.html` and then jump to the element with the ID `diviwant`.
2. When running with Javascript, you want to pass `content.html #diviwant` to jQuery's `load()` method, as that tells jQuery to load only the fragment with the id `diviwant` from the target page.

I'd probably use `content.html#diviwant` as the link, as you've got, then interpret that in the jQuery like this:

```
$("#divtobeloadedwith").load(link.replace('#', ' #'));
```

...to add the necessary space for the `load()`.

Comment: thank you very much Matt, it is working now. `encodeURI()` was doing its thing when i have had put space, but your approach is finer and will make use of it. best!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space between `content.html` and `#diviwant` in the `href` of your link.

```
<li><a href="content.html#diviwant">click</a></li>
```

You also need to make sure that "divtobeloaded" exists.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="content.html#diviwant">click</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="divtobeloaded"></div>
```

Comment: after doing this, it loads all the content, not only specific div

Comment: @daniel Yes, you effectively need both. If you want (with a normal, non-Ajaxy link) to go to the item #diviwant on the page content.html, you need `content.html#diviwant` as the link. If you want *just* to load the #diviwant content from the content.html page using jQuery's `load`, you'll need `content.html #diviwant` (with a space). The obvious approach, from what I can see, would be to use `content.html#diviwant` as the link, and add the space programatically when loading using jQuery.